Git code reviews in Visual Studio 2022 without merging?
I am used to TFVC and I am trying to get to grips with Git in Visual Studio 2022 17.10.3.
In TFVC you could create a code review request before check-in, on pending changes in your local workspace, or on shelved changes. The equivalent of check-in in Git seems to be Commit then Push (so the changes are available in the remote repository), but there does not seem to be anyway to request someone to review your code during this process.
Instead, if my understanding of
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-pull-request?view=vs-2022 is correct, I have to create a pull request from one remote branch to another. Can I not create a pull request from the local branch to which I have committed my changes, to the remote repository?
Imagine in Azure Dev Ops I have an origin/dev branch on which I run nightly build pipelines (this dev branch was branched from origin/main). I have cloned the ADO repository to my local repository. I commit changes to my local dev branch. I want these changes to be code reviewed, ideally before they are pushed to the remote origin/dev. It does not seem there is anyway to do this in Visual Studio. Instead, it seems I need to locally branch from dev, e.g.,
dev2, commit changes to dev2, push dev2 to the remote origin/dev2, and then create a pull request to merge the remote origin/dev2 to origin/dev. The reviewer of the pull request can then review the changes.
With this approach it seems the remote repository will get littered with lots of "dev2" type branches from developers who want their code to be reviewed.
Is this correct or is there an easier way to do this?
I am aware of this issue being raised in the Microsoft Developer community, with no satisfactory resolution: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-review-without-a-pull-request/444630.

In these tools, code review happens on the pull request.... You can get review comments, you can add to the PR branch or rewrite history if possible.... The whole thing can become a single commit after it is finished, from git's POV, strictly speaking, so no middle work is kept in the final stuff that is merged

Also, consider using RFC  to prepend the title of the PR so people know it is not to be merged.

@eftshift0 I think you are saying that I should create the dev2 branch in my example, make changes to it, and then commit that all in one go. The reviewer of the PR can choose to keep the code changes merged to dev but not the dev2 branch itself?

You can create as many commits as you like.... At least git does not care how many commits you make in a branch.... There might be policies in place about it but that's a different topic, not a technical thing from git's POV. So do as many commits as necessary, then push the branch into a place where you can then create the PR from. Just in case, of it is a PFC thing, I think it is ok to feel free in terms of what it's history is.... And then when you are done with the RFC, you can consider rewriting history yo your likes to setup "the real history" of the real PR....

Git is extremely flexible in this topic.... You can create many commits when you are doing development and then clean up the mess by squashing into a single commit before pushing
